# Redis Clusteirng with Python: StirctRedisCluster pubsub.subcribe gives KeyError

Tags: python

I have been trying to configure Redis Cluster with my python wepapp (which is using single redis instance currently)

Since  redis clustering is supported from 3.x, upgraded the redis server version to 3.0.7

Using **redis-py-clusterV1.2.0** module in my python app.

PubSub command to publish and subscribe to a particular channel does not seem to be working with the KeyError as mentioned below in the stack trace. It would be great if somebody can help on this.

```
from rediscluster import StrictRedisCluster
startup_nodes = [{"host": "127.0.0.1", "port": "6379"}]
redis_conn = StrictRedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes,  
             decode_responses=True)
redis_conn.pubsub()
pubsub.subscribe(['a_b:c:d']) //tried with diff keys, getting the same error
```

Stack Trace of the Error:

```
File "/home/<username>/.pex/install/redis-2.10.2-py2-none-
any.whl.621ec5075459e032e02a8654e15c5ca320969b0b/redis-2.10.2-py2-none-
any.whl/redis/client.py",line 2196, in subscribe

ret_val = self.execute_command('SUBSCRIBE', *iterkeys(new_channels))

File "/home/<username>/.pex/install/redis_py_cluster-1.2.0-py2-none-
any.whl.5a485619e4e267bf90b972cf0e736baba918e3cc/redis_py_cluster-1.2.0-py2-
none-any.whl/rediscluster/pubsub.py",line 29, in execute_command

channel=args[1],   

File "/home/<username>/.pex/install/redis_py_cluster-1.2.0-py2-none-
any.whl.5a485619e4e267bf90b972cf0e736baba918e3cc/redis_py_cluster-1.2.0-py2-
none-any.whl/rediscluster/connection.py",line 141, in get_connection

node = self.get_master_node_by_slot(slot)   

File "/home/<username>/.pex/install/redis_py_cluster-1.2.0-py2-none-
any.whl.5a485619e4e267bf90b972cf0e736baba918e3cc/redis_py_cluster-1.2.0-py2-
none-any.whl/rediscluster/connection.py",line 267, inget_master_node_by_slot
return self.nodes.slots[slot][0] 

KeyError: 7226
```

When I debug , got to know self.nodes.slots[] seems to be empty. No clues why I get this error.

Thanks in Advance
Priya